# $.ajax is not working with ASP.NET

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax

I'm trying to call `$.ajax` method to retrieve NORTHWND Employees details based on the search criteria. But, for some reason, `country`, and `title` variable are always returning `null`. I am not understanding where I am doing wrong.

Below is the clear explanation.

Below is the code in `AjaxDemoRequestPage.aspx`

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            Country:
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtCountry" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            Title:
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtTitle" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:Button ID="btnAjax" runat="server" Text="$.ajax()" />
            <div id="container"></div>
        </div>
        <script src="Scripts/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                $("#btnAjax").click(function (evt) {
                    var data = {};
                    data.country = $("#txtCountry").val();
                    data.title = $("#txtTitle").val();
                    debugger;
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "PostTarget.aspx",
                        type: "POST",
                        data: data,
                        contentType: "x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: SuccessfulAjaxResponse,
                        error: ErroticAjaxResponse
                    });
                    evt.preventDefault();
                });
            });
            function SuccessfulAjaxResponse(results, status, jqXHR) {
                $("#container").empty();
                debugger;
                for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                    $("#container").append("<tr>" +
                        "<td>" + results[i].EmployeeID + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + results[i].FirstName + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + results[i].LastName + "</td>"
                        );
                }
            }

            function ErroticAjaxResponse(jqXHR, status, error) {
                alert("Error: " + error);
            }
        </script>
    </form>
```

Below is the code in `PostTarget.aspx.cs` page. In this page, when debugging I am always getting `country`, and `title` as `null`.

```
public partial class PostTarget : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var country = Request.Form["country"];
        var title = Request.Form["title"];
        var db = new NORTHWNDEntities();
        var emps = db.Employees
            .Where(x => x.Country.Contains(country) || x.Title.Contains(title))
            .Select(x => new EmployeeSearchResult
        {
            EmployeeID = x.EmployeeID,
            FirstName = x.FirstName,
            LastName = x.LastName
        });
        Response.Clear();
        Response.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(emps));
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();
    }
}
```

Can anyone please suggest me where I am doing wrong?

Comment: Your ajax request is not calling any function. By the way, the function called should be `static` and tagged `[WebMethod]`

Comment: @BadMiscuit: Whatever you said are not mandatory. They are just one another way of doing. We can do by following the approach how I followed.

Comment: *"is not working"* tells us next to nothing of value. What does the error handler tell you? You should at least provide relevant debugging info.

Comment: The problem is the contentType

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My blunder mistake was that I never made call to `$.ajax` method. Below is the modified and working code.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            Country:
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtCountry" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            Title:
             <asp:TextBox ID="txtTitle" runat="server"></asp:TextBox> 

            <!-- <asp:Button ID="btnAjax" runat="server" Text="$.ajax()" />-->
            <input type="button" id="btnAjax" value="$.ajax()"/>

            <div id="container"></div>
        </div>
        <script src="Scripts/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                $("#btnAjax").click(function (evt) {
                    var data = {};
                    data.country =document.getElementById('<%= txtCountry.ClientID %>').value;
                    data.title = document.getElementById('<%= txtTitle.ClientID %>').value;
                    debugger;
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "PostTarget.aspx",
                        type: "POST",
                        data: data,
                        contentType: "x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: SuccessfulAjaxResponse,
                        error: ErroticAjaxResponse
                    });
                    $.ajax(data);
                    evt.preventDefault();
                });
            });
            function SuccessfulAjaxResponse(results, status, jqXHR) {
                $("#container").empty();
                debugger;
                for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                    $("#container").append("<tr>" +
                        "<td>" + results[i].EmployeeID + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + results[i].FirstName + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + results[i].LastName + "</td>"
                        );
                }
            }

            function ErroticAjaxResponse(jqXHR, status, error) {
                alert("Error: " + error);
            }
        </script>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `contentType` should be this:

```
contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8",
```

Comment: Yes, I tried by modifying as you suggested. But same problem. How come "contentType" could be the problem for NOT getting values into code-behind? Really strange answer.

Comment: I downloaded your code, run it locally and it worked https://github.com/kblok/StackOverflowExamples/blob/master/AspNetDemoProject/AspNetDemoProject/Demos/AjaxDemoRequestPage.aspx . Content type is super important because it tells how the data is packaged.

Comment: In your code, the data is in the post body, which can be accessed and parsed using the InputStream, see https://github.com/kblok/StackOverflowExamples/blob/master/AspNetDemoProject/AspNetDemoProject/Demos/PostTarget.aspx.cs#L15

Answer (score -2):

`ID` generated by ASP.NET will not same as you have given. this is the reason you are getting null value .

You can access ASP.NET control in javascript in this way.

```
document.getElementById('<%= txtCountry.ClientID %>').value
```

And also you can simple use html button instead of ASP.NET button for making ajax request.

Here is your updated code.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            Country:
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtCountry" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            Title:
             <asp:TextBox ID="txtTitle" runat="server"></asp:TextBox> 

            <!-- <asp:Button ID="btnAjax" runat="server" Text="$.ajax()" />-->
            <input type="button" id="btnAjax" value="$.ajax()"/>

            <div id="container"></div>
        </div>
        <script src="Scripts/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                $("#btnAjax").click(function (evt) {
                    var data = {};
                    data.country =document.getElementById('<%= txtCountry.ClientID %>').value;
                    data.title = document.getElementById('<%= txtTitle.ClientID %>').value;
                    debugger;
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "PostTarget.aspx",
                        type: "POST",
                        data: data,
                        contentType: "x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: SuccessfulAjaxResponse,
                        error: ErroticAjaxResponse
                    });
                    evt.preventDefault();
                });
            });
            function SuccessfulAjaxResponse(results, status, jqXHR) {
                $("#container").empty();
                debugger;
                for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                    $("#container").append("<tr>" +
                        "<td>" + results[i].EmployeeID + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + results[i].FirstName + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + results[i].LastName + "</td>"
                        );
                }
            }

            function ErroticAjaxResponse(jqXHR, status, error) {
                alert("Error: " + error);
            }
        </script>
    </form>
```

Comment: Have you tried this program by executing? You please try once, Your program won't work, I guess.